# Can I use same magento theme for different website?

Tags: magento-1.9

So i don't want to create multiple store but my 2 website will selling similar products. Can I use same magento theme for my two different websites?

Comment: DO you have same admin for both your website?

Comment: There will be different admin panel to manage both the websites

Comment: then you need to install same theme in both the website using respective admin panel.

Comment: So do i need to purchase the license of that theme again ?

Comment: If your's sites are like stage & live then probably you can use same If not working then you can spoke to theme providers as you want same theme for stage also. But if not stage live kind websites then you need to purchase.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both websites in same admin then Yes.

**Yes,** Same theme you can use for both website.
Set it from Backend **Admin->System->Configuration->Design->Themes.**

**Yes,** Same products you can use for both websites

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same admin panel for both the website then you can install same theme...